# How to close an area?

Tags: interface

With a UI layout like this:

[image: screenshot]

How do I close the bottom area?

These are the context menus of the header, the split, the editor type selector and the type selector itself:

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot] [image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]

There's an item that allows me to maximize the area, but there is nothing to close it.

Comment: @rjg Not a duplicate. The answers to that question are to use the "Join Areas" command, my question is because that command is *missing* from the context menu.

Comment: Alright, my bad.

Comment: Subdivide the bottom part to match the upper one then merge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found one weird way:

I can split the bottom area vertically as well and then align the split borders of the top and bottom area pairs:

[image: screenshot]

This alignment is easily possible because the split borders snap to a grid.

As soon as they are aligned, the context menu of the border between any top and bottom area gets a new item "Join areas":

[image: screenshot]

After joining the left pair and the right pair, the bottom area is then gone.

Comment: yes I think it's a new feature, but instead of Join Areas you should be able to grab one of the window corner and push it / pull it to collapse the other window

Comment: @moonboots Nope, that also only works after aligning the splits.

Comment: Oh ok didn't know that

Comment: Hello :). This question keeps popping up as unanswered. Please mark your question as accepted, to keep the site nice and tidy.